# map nodes to data

Tags: javascript, dom, associative-array

I'd like to create a correlation between data and DOM nodes. I tried to directly create a Object, with the nodes as properties, but it looks like only the string representations of the nodes are used.

To make the problem more concrete, let's say I have the below document, and I want to associate the first `div` with the number `3`, and the second `div` with the list `['x', 'y', 'z']`, how would you do this?

```
<html> <body>
<div/>
<div/>
( 100 more divs )
</body> </html>
```

I see that jQuery has a [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method just for doing this. Is that the only way? This seems like such a fundamental operation that I had expected to do it with plain-old javascript.

The intent is to register an onclick event with these nodes, and have the data on hand.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var index2data = { 0:3, 1:['x', 'y', 'z'] };
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
        setData( divs[i], index2data[i] )
        divs[i].onclick = onClick;
    }
}

function onClick() {
    var data = getData( this );
    // do a bunch more stuff
}
```

Comment: Please stop tagging your titles. It's a shame that you've been doing this for almost two years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order of keeping the actual data separate from the DOM you can try to set div IDs for all elements by script - in doing so you should test if any div already has an id and use that instead in order of not breaking things...

```
var obj={};
function setDivIdsAndData(dataToSet)
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
       var divId="d"+i;
       if (divs[i].getAttribute("id")==null)
           divs[i].setAttribute("id",divId);
       else
           divId=divs[i].getAttribute("id");
       obj[divId]=dataToSet[i];
    }
};
```

And now applied to your example case:

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    var index2data = { 0:3, 1:['x', 'y', 'z'] };
    setDivIdsAndData(index2data);
};

function onClick() 
{
    var data = obj[this.getAttribute("id")];
    // do a bunch more stuff
};
```

Comment: into the innerHTML property http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: if you want to do it without using any means of addressing the divs it will be more difficult to do...

Comment: Can you elaborate on this I'm not sure I get this correctly. Do you want to put the data into the divs or not? I understood that you wanted the content of div one be '3' and div 2 be 'xyz'

Comment: Sorry, then I simply misinterpreted what you wanted. I added what should fit your needs to the answer.

Comment: ah, I see give me a second there

Comment: I tried adding something that would do it the other way around see if it helps you...

Comment: I added a function you could build upon to assign ids to the divs by script. That way you don't have to rely on the divs position in the dom as the only known variable available to you...

Comment: @bukzor I have applied the function I wrote to set the div ids and to associate the data based on the ids to your updated use case scenario from the question.

Comment: @C.O. Thanks. Essentially you're creating a string ID which can be attached to the node and also used as a key into `obj`. This is in general similar to Remy Sharp's solution as well. I had hoped to keep my data separate from the DOM namespace, but it seems like that's not a concern for JS.

Comment: @bukzor I cleaned it up. There might be a way to do it without adding the ids... You could keep a two dimensional array with a reference to a div as one index of any row and your data as the other. The cost would be that you'd have to iterate over the entire array each time you need some data. As in order to retrieve something you'd have to compare the current div object to the object references stored on the array until you find a match...

Comment: @C.O. Thanks, it looks good. That would be like implementing a hash table with a linked list. No good. Feel free to give a second answer if you have a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set an attribute with the JSON encoded data against it. In the examples I've provided I'm adding the data using the boot up JavaScript, but there's no reason this shouldn't already be on in the markup delivered by your server.

Then the `getData` method just reads the attribute and JSON parses it:

```
function getData(el) {
  return JSON.parse(el.getAttribute('data-stuff'));
}
```

Note that I've just called the data attribute 'data-stuff' - as data-* attribute a valid HTML5 - obviously name it more appropriately.

Working example without jQuery: http://jsbin.com/opugax/edit

Working example with jQuery: http://jsbin.com/opugax/2/edit

Note that if you don't want to use jQuery, and do want to support IE7 and below - you'll need to include json2.js in your page: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: In general, is there no guideline against injecting data into the DOM? I'd like to keep my data and DOM separate, but it seems like this is the only way. Here's my try of keeping them separate, but it doesn't work :( http://jsbin.com/elaxod/4

Comment: Obviously it depends entirely on the problem you're trying to solve, but if you data is specific to the DOM element as you've suggested, attaching it to a data-foo attribute is perfectly legal, but also makes sense to do. Your example you've provided doesn't like that you're using a DOM element as a key, so it fails. More info data-* attributes here: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: I should also add - if you want to keep your DOM and data separate, then it may suggest that the key to the data isn't the DOM element, and rather the data should have a reference back to the DOM (rather than the other way around). This would obviously be a more "traditional" way of linking data to the DOM. But - it doesn't work if your logic is DOM-centric - it's all about the specific problem you're trying to solve :)

Comment: Sorry - last comment! The important factor about doing it using a data-* attribute is that the initial data can delivered in the markup by the server.  If that doesn't matter - then you might as well just use the suggestion below and attach an arbitrary data property to the DOM element.

Comment: Thanks! That's great information. I guess at the core of it, I'm trying to convert a DOM node into something hashable. In Python I'd have two choices, but I don't see one in javascript. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hash

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is simple, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to accomplish your overall goal.

**The DOM is extensible.**

All that is needed to add data to an element is to assign it to the DOM object, either when the element is created or afterward. Here's an afterward example using the elements ID to reference it:

```
var divObj = document.getElementById('link1');
divObj.data = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

The data is not an HTML attribute of the element, but a node extension of the DOM which can hold any type of data including functions/methods.

Accessing and working with this data is as simple as assigning it above:

```
var divObj = document.getElementById('link1');
doSomething(divObj.data);
```

Your goal was to access it with an event handler, which depends on your method of assigning events. I use the more modern obj.addEventListener, and obj.attachEvent (MSIE). Getting the target object that was clicked is a bit different from the simple obj.onclick() assignment, but accessing the data is the same.

Comment: Thanks. That solution came to mind, and it does solve the problem nicely, except doesn't it bother anyone to convolute the DOM and the application data structures? I was trying to hold them separate.

Comment: I'm too new to JS to have realized the practical limitations of storing objects in the DOM and I've yet to find anyone with wisdom on the topic. If your research reveals a better convention, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A collection of div nodes is an ordered list- source code order.
Use an array to hold your data and assign the same indexed div that data.

```
var dom= /*[parent]*/.getElementsByTagName('div'),
data= // reference the data array.
L= Math.min(data.length,dom.length),
next;

while(L){
next= data[--L];
if(next!= undefined) dom[L].setAttribute('data-association', next);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following this. I don't understand your use of commas or `next`. Also I see an unclosed `{`.